# Vertex Coordinate Values in Global positions?

Tags: coordinates

I've been using Blender 2.7 for a number of years, and I get very specific with my vertex locations by setting the transform XYZ to Global numbers instead of local.  This has allowed me to make very accurate models of items for printing.

Now I have moved to Blender 2.93, and I can't seem to find a way to display the coordinates in the user interface in a Global framework.  I'm not talking about the Global reference at the top that allows movement in the Global vs. Local vs. Normal directions....I'm talk about the actual XYZ location of a vertex.  All I can seem to get is relative positions.

Is that functionality gone?  Is there a way to see the XYZ location of a vertex from a Global reference?
Thanks for any suggestions!

[image]

Comment: in 2.9, the transforms appear in the Sidebar, on the right side of the 3D viewport. It's visibility is toggled with the N key. Transforms appear under Item and _are_ global.

Comment: I do see the location you're talking about with the "N" key.  I was looking at the wrong "Location" information.  Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.